# Ucfirst all strings within <strong> tag

Tags: php

I am trying to Ucfirst all strings within `<strong>` in a sentence. Tried this without any luck:

```
 function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname)
 {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname>(.*?)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return ucfirst($matches[1]);
 }

$sentence = "Yellow pitty lies <strong>about</strong> the life.";

$finalsentence = getTextBetweenTags($sentence,"strong");
```

What is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: in that particular example, it works fine. what do you mean without any luck?

Comment: Use a different delimiter than `/` in your pattern so that you won't need to escape it later: `$pattern = "~<$tagname>(.*?)</$tagname>~";`

Comment: If you found the answer you were looking for, please mark it as "Accepted" (green checkbox below the up/down arrows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include matching for the text before and after the tags.

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname)
 {
    $pattern = "/(.*<$tagname>)(.*?)(<\/$tagname>.*)/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1] . ucfirst($matches[2]) . $matches[3];
 }

$sentence = "Yellow pitty lies <strong>about</strong> the life.";

$finalsentence = getTextBetweenTags($sentence,"strong");
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler way.  Instead of using php you could use only css, for instance:

```
strong:first-letter{
    text-transform: capitalize
}
```

Comment: Simplicity is beautiful!

Comment: Need to add this, that won't work if the strong tag is "display:block" and if you do that, it works seperated with other elements, like if you hover the sentence, only hovered element underlined instead of underlined together. Simpliest fix, but I must check the other answer. Thanks :)